# Are the 2 planeswalker sets from Amonkhet balanced?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

New player here, looking to play very casually with my wife. We bought the 2 Amonkhet planeswalker decks ([Liliana, death wielder](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bLiliana%2c%20death%20wielder%5d) and [Gideon, martial paragon](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bGideon%2c%20martial%20paragon%5d)). Are these 2 decks designed specifically to be balanced against one another? or will one of these 2 have an advantage?

Comment: For 2 balanced decks to play with I would rather go for the duel decks. They are created and playtested to be somewhat on the same power level.

Comment: @counterflux The planeswalker decks have been released as a replacement for the duel decks so unless you meant a duel deck from a previous set, it's not possible to get them anymore

Comment: @ryu The planeswalker decks replace the intro decks or event decks or whatever they were called. Duel decks are still happening, if speed vs cunning is any indication

Answer (score 1):

In the [official announcement post](http://magic.wizards.com/en/articles/archive/news/amonkhet-planeswalker-deck-lists-2017-04-19), the following line is mentioned, from which you could deduce that these decks are meant to be played against each other:

> The decks are meant for newer players but can be fun for anyone to battle them against one another.

Of course, whether decks are balanced in practice is always questionable, and other than the decklists also depends on the skill of the players which are playing them, and their affinity to the deck's theme. Generally, you should end up with a somewhat balanced deck, however - very likely more balanced than any two random decks you would construct from your card pool on your own.